# How to rerender a rich:dataTable

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, java-ee-5, seam2

I'm having trouble rerendering a `<rich:dataTable>` in JSF. I have a refresh link on my page that should refresh only the content

```
<h:commandLink action="#" value="#{messages['listmsgs.header.refresh']}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender="mesagesListTable" />
</h:commandLink>
```

But when I hit this button, nothing happens. When I press F5, nothing happens, too. If I click the link that leads me to the current page, nothing happens either. Only when I click a link to another page and go back (not via back button of the browser), the content is rerendered. How can I enforce that effect with a reRender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerender the parent component of the dataTable. For example you could put the dataTable inside a h:panelGroup and reRender the panelGroup.

Comment: It does not seem to work. Maybe it has something to do with Hibernate. I noticed that when the table gets a new row, the table is updated. But when a cell value changes, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you saving the collections that feeds the table somewhere or do you read it from the database each time the getter is called?

Comment: I read it every time the getter is called. But I've found the solution: I called entityManager.clear() in the getter, now it works. Thanks for your comments